# Can't remove line breaks from BeautifulSoup text output (Python 2.7.5)

Tags: python, text, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write a program to parse a series of HTML files and store the resulting data in a .csv spreadsheet, which is incredibly reliant on newlines being in exactly the right place. I've tried every method I can find to strip the linebreaks away from certain pieces of text, to no avail. The relevant code looks like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
ID = soup.td.get_text()
ID.strip()
ID.rstrip()
ID.replace("\t", "").replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "")
dateCreated = soup.td.find_next("td").get_text()
dateCreated.replace("\t", "").replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "")
dateCreated.strip()
dateCreated.rstrip()
# debug
print('ID:' + ID + 'Date Created:' + dateCreated)
```

And the resulting code looks like this:

```
ID:
FOO
Date Created:
BAR
```

This and another problem with the same program have been driving me up the wall. Help would be fantastic. Thanks.

EDIT: Figured it out, and it was a pretty stupid mistake. Instead of just doing

```
ID.replace("\t", "").replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "")
```

I should have done

```
ID = ID.replace("\t", "").replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "")
```

Comment: Try printing `repr(ID)` to see what bytes might be in there?  Otherwise, maybe try string formatting instead of concatenation?

Comment: Printing repr(ID) and repr(dateCreated) gave me u'\nFOO\n'
u'\nBAR\n'. I already tried setting the replacements to (u"\n", u"") but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue at hand is that you're expecting in-place operations from what are actually operations that return new values.

```
ID.strip() # returns the rstripped value, doesn't change ID.
ID = ID.strip() # Would be more appropriate.
```

You could use regex, though regex is overkill for this process.  Realistically, especially if it's beginning and ending characters, just pass them to strip:

```
ID = ID.strip('\t\r\n')
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an internal implementation of **Stripped Strings** for BeautifulSoup4

> These strings tend to have a lot of extra whitespace, which you can remove by using the .stripped_strings generator instead:
>   [BS4 Doc stripped_strings](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings)

```
html_doc="""<div class="path">
    <a href="#"> abc</a>
    <a href="#"> def</a>
    <a href="#"> ghi</a>
</div>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

result_list = []
for s in soup.select("div.path"):
    result_list.extend(s.stripped_strings)

print  " ".join(result_list)
```

---

```
Output: abc def ghi
```

Answer (score 3):

Even though this question has kind of already been answered, I just wanted to through out that there's not a great reason to do a replace in that verbose way, you can actually do this:

```
import re

ID = re.sub(r'[\t\r\n]', '', ID)
```

Even though `regex` is generally something to be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this. The other solutions looked complicated or didn't quite address the OP. This one-liner works fine:

```
' '.join(re.split(r'[ \n\t]+',soup.text))
```