# How to delete /r and resolve the weird formating issue I have with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to scrape PGA Golf Schedules from the PGA Website https://www.pgatour.com/tournaments/schedule.html but run into issues when I tackle this with Beautiful Soup. When I print the dataframe it has a weird format and lot of \r signs which I can't replace like I've done it with \n.

```
...

URL = "https://www.pgatour.com/tournaments/schedule.html"
response = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")

table = soup.find("table",{"class":"table-styled"}).tbody

rows = table.find_all("tr")
columns = [v.text.replace("\n","",) for v in rows [0].find_all("td")]


print(df)
```

unfortunately I got a mess back:

```
   Oct\r            4 - 7\r          \
0  Oct\r            11 - 14\r           

  Safeway Open\r\r            \r                \r                    Silverado Resort and Spa North, \r                    Napa, \r                    CA \r                    \r                \r            \r            • Purse: $6,400,000\r              \
0  CIMB Classic\r\r            \r                ...                                                                                                                                                                                                               

       \
0       

  \r            \r                \r                \r                \r                \r                    Kevin Tway\r                \r            \r            \r                \r                    $1,152,000\r                \r            \r          \
0  \r            \r                \r            ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

   500  
0  500
```

so I have following Questions:

1. Why do I have a lot of  \r signs and how can I replace/delete them accordingly ?
2. Why is the format so messed up and how can i fix this ?

Thanks for any help!

I tried to do the same with what I did to replace \n but that did't work out :

```
columns = [v.text.replace("\r","",) for v in rows [0].find_all("td")]
```

Comment: Where are you creating df above?

Comment: in python 3, jupyter

Comment: I meant the code probably should be 'print(columns)' not df..  those \r are hard returns, you can see it when you print the soup. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878437/cant-remove-line-breaks-from-beautifulsoup-text-output-python-2-7-5

Comment: thanks that solved Problem 1(replacing r)! Regarding Problem 2 : Do you have an idea why my format is so weird and what can be done about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas` library to read_html() to load data into dataframe.
However you can import data into `csv` file. BeautufulSoup is not required.

```
import pandas as pd
dfs=pd.read_html('https://www.pgatour.com/tournaments/schedule.html')
print(dfs[1])
#To import data into csv file
dfs[1].to_csv('outdata.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: thats really smart, thanks! Would you recommend to not use BeautifulSoup at all ?

Comment: In this scenario it is not required to use beautiful soup.since your target to get table data and load into data frame.